# JQuery DataTable Search Box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be able to programatically filter a jquery datatable using the same default filtering functionality as the built-in datatable search box, but I cannot figure out how to access this functionality. I would like to be able to do something like:
  $('#sample_1').dataTable().Filter("word to filter with using all rows loaded into datatable"). Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like **fnFooterCallback** to customise the result-sets and perform additional tasks based upon the search filter. I don't have an example to share it with you but this link i.e http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/730/how-to-manually-recall-the-fnfootercallback-function/p1 could help you to achieve what you are looking for. And also, there are bunch of other interesting [datatable callbacks](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks), make sure you check them out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did solve like this case as follow, not using the filter function, but passing the value and triggering the existing filter function.

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/w30jpdk2/8/**

Key in any work in the table and click search button.

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "paginate": {
                "next": "Next page"
            }
        }
    });
    // custom filter
    $('#btn_search').on('click', function(){
        $('.dataTables_filter input').val($('#cus_search').val()).keyup();
    });
});
```